# Multiple instances of same view in 2 regions on one view MVVM / Prism / WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

i have sort of the same question but i don't understand the answers on this page.

[Am I doing it correctly do deal with multiple instances of same view in MVVM / Prism / WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915879/am-i-doing-it-correctly-do-deal-with-multiple-instances-of-same-view-in-mvvm-p)

what i'm trying to do is the following.

i have a main apllication with the MainWindow, on that window i have a tabcontrol with a region called 'tabregion'.

then i have I have a module with a mainView with 2 regions 'region1' and 'region2' and this view loads in the tabcontrol on the mainwindow .

then i have one view (VideoPanel) witch is verry big (a view for streaming a webcam) i realy like to have the opportunity to stream 2 webcams(or more) on one page with the same view(VideoPanel), so i would like to load the view(Videopanel) to region 1 and 2.

this is what i do now in the module

```
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        var regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Video1Region", typeof(VideoPanel));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Video2Region", typeof(VideoPanel));

    }
```

it works but not perfectly. because some of the settings that i use are messed up.

Then i tried loading the view(VideoPanel) in the regions when loading the mainView and then add parameters to it

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCmd}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

```
private void LoadedCmd(RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            var par1 = new NavigationParameters
                {
                    { "Id", 1 }
                };

            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("Region1", nameof(VideoPanel), par1);

            var par2 = new NavigationParameters
                {
                    { "Id", 2 }
                };

            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("Region2", nameof(VideoPanel), par2);
        }
```

but the navigation aware is not working in the view(VideoPanel), so i  dont get the id that i want to send to my viewmodel.

I hope you understand my problem because my english is not that good.

Comment: What type of region is `Region1` ? Some controls can host a single view only, some can host multiple, depending on the `RegionAdapter` used.

Comment: sorry i didn't explain that, both region 1 and 2 are ContentControls

Comment: I made a mistake in my qeustion, there was 2 times region 1 but it has to be region 1 and 2 offcourse, sorry i corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

As I am the author of the post you linked I will try to explained how I have done in our application.

First be sure that the ViewModel is implementing **INavigationAware** but regarding your post it seems that you have done it.

Then we have registered the views for navigation in our module

```cs
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Axes2View>();
}
```

So if you remove your **RegisterViewWithRegion** you need to call at some place where you have the regionManager available (through dependency injection for exemple)

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionName, viewName, navParameters);
```

And depending where you put these calls (one for each instance) you should have a flag to do the navigation only once per region. Be careful that the Regions may not be created too early.

And finally in the Viewmodel you can manage the parameters in **IsNavigationTarget** to create a new instance if need, and in **OnNavigatedTo** depending on what should be done with the parameters.